# DisplayName not being displayed by DisplayFor helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP MVC ViewModel, I have the following properties that are using the `DisplayName` identifier

```
    [DisplayName("Payment Frequency")]
    public char paymentFrequency { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Account Type")]
    public char accountType { get; set; }
```

However when they are called by the `DipslayFor` helper in the view like so

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.paymentFrequency) 
    </div>

    <div class="M-editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.accountType)
    </div>
```

I get a big ol' blank space. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DisplayName is the Label Display value ->

use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.paymentFrequency)`

you're getting blanks because you have empty properties i'm guessing.

Usually you use LabelFor and DisplayFor with eachother to display the label and the value.